# Examples using Primefaces with Pivot4J

Tags: primefaces, mdx, olap4j

Sorry if this is a noob question.

I am currently looking at using Primefaces as the front end to display data from a OLAP4J cube and MDX. I have looked at the Pivot4J analytics app and this works fine, but would like a simpler example to retrieve the data and render it in a Primefaces grid.

I have searched and cannot find such a simple example to understand how this fits together. Is there such documentation / examples?

Comment: hi Andy S-O is really code related: your question isn't massively code related so will probably not get much attention and might get down-voted or closed. Do those products you mention have user groups?

Comment: Thank you for your response and the clarification. I have had no luck doing searches as there is a distinct lack of documentation. I will try their forums, but thought I would try here first as the other forums do not seem to be well used.

Comment: Hey @AndyC, any luck with this issue? I am searching for the same stuff and I was wondering whether you could shed some light in the path.